# Transform single row into two rows based on two columns values

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['b_code', 'c_code', 'name'], data = [[3401560221954, 6275442, 'name 1'], [987510, 987510, 'name 2'], [4473089, '', 'name 3'], ['', 9584362, 'name 4']])
```

The above dataframe is a sample set. My dataframe has 70 columns.

What I would like to do is to transform single rows into two rows if two columns 'b_code' and 'c_code' have different values. I am looking for output as below:

```
    b_code            c_code   name
0   3401560221954              name 1
1                     6275442  name 1
2        987510       987510   name 2
3        4473089               name 3
4                     9584362  name 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean mask for duplicated rows with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal, then filter original and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together rows with changed codes with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and index for 100% correct ordering, because default algo also in [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) is unstable `quicksort`:

```
mask = my_df['c_code'].ne(my_df['b_code']) & my_df['b_code'].ne('') & my_df['c_code'].ne('')
```

Alternative `mask`:

```
mask = my_df['c_code'].ne(my_df['b_code']) & my_df[['b_code','c_code']].eq('').sum(1).ne(1)

print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

df = my_df[mask]
print (df)
          b_code   c_code    name
0  3401560221954  6275442  name 1

df = pd.concat([df.assign(b_code = '').rename(lambda x: x + .3), 
                df.assign(c_code = '').rename(lambda x: x + .5),  
                my_df[~mask]]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
          b_code   c_code    name
0                 6275442  name 1
1  3401560221954           name 1
2         987510   987510  name 2
3        4473089           name 3
4                 9584362  name 4
```

If ordering is not important in duplicated rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df.assign(b_code = ''), 
                df.assign(c_code = ''),  
                my_df[~mask]]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about manually partitioning the dataframe into parts you want to replicate and parts not to be replicated, replicate, and then concatenate everything back together.

```
cond = (my_df.c_code != my_df.b_code) & (my_df.b_code != '') & (my_df.c_code != '')
repl1 = my_df[cond].copy()
repl1['b_code'] = ''
repl2 = my_df[cond].copy()
repl2['c_code'] = ''
pd.concat([my_df[~cond], repl1, repl2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)


          b_code   c_code    name
0                 6275442  name 1
1  3401560221954           name 1
2         987510   987510  name 2
3        4473089           name 3
4                 9584362  name 4
```

This does not guarantee the row order of the replication. If you want to guarantee order, you can change the index for one of the replicas. So to get exactly same order as your example, you can do this for `repl1` before the last line of code:

```
repl1.index = np.arange(len(repl1)) + 0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by and apply to achieve this. In apply function you can check the condition and split row if your condition match by appending a new row

```py
def split_row(x):
    x= x.copy()
    if (type(x.iloc[0].b_code) is int and type(x.iloc[0].c_code) is int) \
        and (x.iloc[0].b_code != x.iloc[0].c_code):
        new_row = x.copy()
        new_row.b_code=""
        x.c_code = ""
        x=x.append(new_row)

    return x


my_df.groupby(["b_code", "c_code"]).apply(split_row).reset_index(drop=True)
```